# ReactJS when using HTML attribute checked, reactjs is not allowing to select the checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, reactjs

As in the question title, I am not able to mark the checkbox as selected, on onChange event of the selectbox like this,

```
<select id='featuresType'
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'type')} >
 {this.getOptions(featuresType)}
 </select>
```

were as the handleChange is like :

```
 handleChange: function (field, e) { 
            if (field == 'type') {
                let selected = e.target.value;
                this.setState({typeSelected: selected})
            }
            /*Why the console is taking the previous selecte option, ex: if Locker is selectec below lone prints 'dc' */
             console.log(field ,',',  this.state.typeSelected)
        },
```

when it is bind to defaultValue,

`defaultChecked={(this.state.typeSelected =='locker')}`

1. The select box is not able to mark wrt the condition given, but manually could able to mark checked/notchecked.

`checked={(this.state.typeSelected =='locker')}`

2. On this checked attribute, the checkbox is able to mark as checked, based on select box option value. BUT in this case the manual way of checking or 
   un-checking is not happening.

Hope you guys got my problem

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/30374/)

I wanted the checkbox to act both ways, on select of the option, the checkbox should be checked. And also user can check/Uncheck the checkbox Manully

Answer (score 1):

[React Docs says](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
> pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
> method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState
> and calls may be batched for performance gains.